# Jquery UI drop event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using jquery ui and my page have set of four blocks which are drow by ul,li stuff, my problem is, When I drop any li element from one block (container) to other block lets says A Block to B block, When I am fetching all element from Block B using below code

```
$("ul#my_"+endblock+" > li").each(function(key, value) {
```

Where `my_"+endblock+"` is id of Block B, I am not getting all element ( li )

ie One li is missing which I drop into Block B, How can I get all element of
Block B

Thanks

Comment: Can you post comple code?

Comment: $("#my_"+endblock+" > li").each(function(index, value) {
 alert(index+"-----"+value);
 });  for example if after drop any li into Block B , updated li not comes into loop , it's fetch old li

Comment: can you include all of your `droppable` and `draggable` code here for further analysis?

Comment: Below is code 
$("#my_"+endblock+" > li").each(function(index, value) {
 $.each( value, function( key, value1 ) {
 if(key == 'id') {
 if(value1.length > 0) {
  if(j !=0) {
    var splitData = value1.split("_");
    myString = myString + "_" +splitData[1]+"|"+j;
  } else {
   var splitData = value1.split("_");
   myString = myString + splitData[1]+"|"+j;
  }
  j++;
 }
 }
  });
});